# regex for specific group of parts of speech selection

Tags: python, regex

Hey i have been trying regex to select these pos patterns

```
JJ JJ JJ JJ 
JJ JJ JJ NNS 
JJ JJ NN NN 
JJ JJ NN
JJ JJ NNS
JJ JJ RB
JJ JJ
JJ NN IN DT JJ
JJ NN JJ NNS
JJ NN JJ
JJ NN NN NN
JJ NN NN
JJ NN NNS
JJ NN
JJ NNP
JJ NNS IN NN
JJ NNS IN NN
JJ NNS NN
JJ NNS NNS
JJ NNS
JJ VBG NNS
JJ VBZ NNS
JJR NN
```

I have tried with the below regex and it doesn't seem to be selecting everything can someone help me with this.

```
(((JJ|NN)\w?)+ ((NN\w?\s?)+|(JJ\s?)+|(RB\s?)+|(IN\s?)+|(DT\s?)+|(VB\w?\s?)+))
```

Comment: `.*` would select them all.

Comment: @ScottHunter i want only those mentioned above to be selected.

Comment: You could just OR together each of the acceptable strings.

Comment: i want it to be more effecient :( not just with an OR

Comment: How about [this](https://regex101.com/r/ZN8kU1/2)?

Comment: @Toto: Accepts strings not in list (for example, "JJX NN").

Comment: @ScottHunter: Yes, it does. I've keep the `\w` from OP. They just need to replace this `\w` with correct alternatives, it's up to them.

Comment: @Toto thanks but iam looking for a solution that only accepts these strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply build an expression from the list of patterns with a `|` separator.  You only need to ensure that longer patterns come before shorter ones because the `|` operator is not greedy:

```
patterns = """JJ JJ JJ JJ 
JJ JJ JJ NNS 
JJ JJ NN NN 
JJ JJ NN
JJ JJ NNS
JJ JJ RB
JJ JJ
JJ NN IN DT JJ
JJ NN JJ NNS
JJ NN JJ
JJ NN NN NN
JJ NN NN
JJ NN NNS
JJ NN
JJ NNP
JJ NNS IN NN
JJ NNS IN NN
JJ NNS NN
JJ NNS NNS
JJ NNS
JJ VBG NNS
JJ VBZ NNS
JJR NN"""

import re
pattern = "|".join(sorted(patterns.split("\n"),key=len,reverse=True))

results = re.findall(pattern,patterns) # finds them all in 0.009 ms
```

This is 3 times faster than a complex expression:

```
pattern = '^((JJ(?:R)*\s*)+\s*((((NN(?:S|P)*|VB(:?G|Z)*|RB|JJ)\s*))+\s*)+(((IN|NN(?:S|P)*|DT|JJ)\s*))*)$'
results = re.findall(pattern,patterns) 
# takes forever (possibly because of new lines in the text).

# taking end of lines out of the equation:
singleLine = patterns.replace("\n","*")
result     = re.findall(pattern, singleLine)
# takes 0.030 ms
```

Comment: This was *explicitly* ruled out by OP in comments; but then accepted a solution that accepts things not on this list, so who knows?

Comment: The simple OR solution performs at least twice as fast as the accepted answer (for small texts) and responds in linear time.  The accepted answer takes exponentially more time depending on the content of the text to search.  For example, searching in the string containing all the patterns takes more than 2 minutes (I wasn't patient enough to wait for it) where the OR solution does it in 0.01 ms.

Comment: *I'm* not the one you have to convince :)

Comment: I would not even have posted this question if I was planning to use a simple OR but I am looking for a better regex if there is any without an OR.

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution, less efficient than @Alain. It matches all the desired strings and none other:

```
^JJR? (?:JJ|NN[PS]?|VB[GZ]?)(?: (?:JJ|NNS?|RB|IN)(?: (?:JJ|NNS?|DT)(?: JJ)?)?)? *$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uNzskS/2)